# Read normal text on webpage with Python

Tags: python

I wonder if there a way to read the text of a webpage to compare to other values,like this
webpage: "Tacos"
Python program:

```
x=the webpage text
 if x == 'Tacos':
 print('The text is: ', x)
```

Comment: _I wonder if there a way to read the text of a webpage to compare to other values_ Most likely, yes. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web scraping is a very common task to do with Python. If you have a direct link to the webpage you want to get the text from, then you can use `get` requests to get the HTML:

```
from requests import get

html_as_text = get(url_to_webpage).text
```

and then you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = BeautifulSoup(html_as_text, 'html.parser')
print(html.prettify())
```

if you don't have a direct link to the webpage, you can use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to navigate to it.

Comment: from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url_to_webpage = 'http://www.google.com'
html_as_text = get(url_to_webpage)
html = BeautifulSoup(html_as_text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
i wrote this but i get a error    html = BeautifulSoup(html_as_text, 'html.parser')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 307, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: Oops, that's my bad. You need `.text` at the end of the get function. Edited the answer with correct code.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience,but now i get a error NameError: name 'soup' is not defined

Comment: ah you need to type `html.prettify()` instead of soup